# IFrame links traces

Tags: html, iframe

Consider the following scenario:

I own `www.a.com` , and in my index page I open an IFrame that goes  to `www.b.com` . The page at `www.b.com` contains a link to `www.c.com` .

If a user clicks on that link, can the owner of site `www.c.com` know that the link originated from my website at `www.a.com`, even though it was through an iframe?

Thanks!!

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the link is on `www.b.com`, the HTTP referer will show it came from `www.b.com`.

One way to get around this is have a redirect page on your server which acts as a middle man, so the link on `www.b.com` will link to `www.a.com/redirect.asp?link=www.c.com`.

If you don't have access to anything on www.b.com there is nothing you can do I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you posted (code for your page would be nice), no.  However, the link from b.com to c.com could contain referrer information, of course.